# jQuery plugin to work without element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How does one make a jQuery plugin that is possible to execute without using an element selector?

Like, usually it's:
`$('#myElementID').myPluginFunction(myVariables);`
But, instead:
`$.myPluginFunction(myVariables);`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually you just use `$.extend()` instead of `$.fn.extend()`, read [here](http://asimilia.wordpress.com/2008/12/17/jquery-extend-confusion/) for more

```
$.fn.extend({
   myMethod: function(){...}
});
//jQuery("div").myMethod();

$.extend({
 myMethod2: function(){...}
});
//jQuery.myMethod();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
$.myPluginFunction = function(vars) {
    //...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.extend`. Here's a small example:

```
$(function() {
    return $.extend({
      addDebugBorder: function(selection, size) {
        return selection.each(function() {
          var color, randomColor;
          randomColor = function() {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
          };
          if (!size) size = '5px';
          color = 'rgb(' + randomColor() + ',' + randomColor() + ', ' + randomColor() + ')';
          return $(this).css('border', size + ' solid ' + color);
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Then called like

```
$.addDebugBorder($("table tr td"), '1px');
```

edit- This example code should really have been a normal plugin, I think I modified it to take the selector rather then just working on div's only is why its a little weird.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning the plugin to the `jQuery.fn` object, just assign it to the root jQuery object itself.

```js
jQuery.myPluginFunction = function(myVariables) {
   // plugin code
}
```